# Mysql not in statement not working

Tags: mysql

Simplifying question:

If I have the following (where CN = name, UID = emp. ID, and supervisor = the emp. ID of supervisor):

```
CN          UID      supervisor  
Jerry       4         NULL
Dave        11        15    
Dan         12        16    
Jack        13        17    
Jason       14        11    
Tom         10        15    
Berry       16        12
```

I expect that neither Dave or Dan be on the list because they are supervisors too (2nd or greater).

```
    SELECT
reports_accreditallfr.cn,
reports_accreditallfr.uid,
reports_accreditallfr.supervisor
FROM
reports_accreditallfr
WHERE
reports_accreditallfr.uid NOT IN ( reports_accreditallfr.supervisor)
```

My current statement gives everything.  I am guessing my NOT IN statement is only working row by row and not scanning the entire supervisor column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery.

```
SELECT reports_accreditallfr.cn, reports_accreditallfr.uid,
       reports_accreditallfr.supervisor
FROM reports_accreditallfr
WHERE reports_accreditallfr.uid NOT IN (select reports_accreditallfr.supervisor
                                        from reports_accreditallfr
                                        where reports_accreditallfr.supervisor is not null
                                       );
```

Your expression is equivalent to:

```
reports_accreditallfr.uid <> reports_accreditallfr.supervisor
```

This is presumably true on all rows.

Comment: beat me by a second. Tell me when you log off, I will log back in then. :P

Comment: This works if I use the IN statement but not the NOT IN.  The NOT IN gives me nothing when it should produce about 80% of my original table.

Comment: @blankip . . . Presumably, that is because the `supervisor` field has `NULL` values, which causes `NOT IN` to fail.  The sample data in the question does not have `NULL` values, so I didn't include the check.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Dang you are right!  I have 5 people in a table of thousands with NULL as supervisor.  So that throws off the whole thing?

Comment: @blankip . . . Yes.  Remember `NULL` means "unknown value".  So, by SQL logic, you can't tell if something is *not* in a list that has an unknown value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Should I replace the NULLs with a value, take them off the list, or edit subquery?

Comment: @blankip . . . Add the `where` clause in the subquery, as in the answer (I edited it a few minutes ago).

Comment: Awesome - Big thank you.  Banging my head for two hours because of 5 NULLS out of 120K people... dumb dumb dumb... didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Good answer. I wanted to include a note that a sbuquery isn't an absolute necessity. An equivalent result can be obtained using an "anti-join" pattern, which often performs better than a query that uses a `NOT IN (subquery)` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit rows that have a value in the `uid` column that appears in the `supervisor` column (for at least one row in the table), and if `uid` is guaranteed to be unique,

Yyou can get that using an "anti-join" pattern:

```
SELECT r.cn
     , r.uid
     , r.supervisor
  FROM reports_accreditallfr r
  LEFT
  JOIN reports_accreditallfr s
    ON s.supervisor = r.uid
 WHERE s.supervisor IS NULL
```

NOTE: the LEFT JOIN operation returns all rows from `r`, the `WHERE` clause omits any row that had at least one matching row from `s` returned.

One slight difference with this query compared to the query in the selected answer. This query will return rows that have a NULL value in `uid`, while the query in the selected answer will omit those (because the predicate `NULL NOT IN (foo)` will not return "true".

The query in the selected answer could be modified to include an `OR uid IS NULL` predicate to match this query; --or-- this query could be changed to include an `AND r.uid IS NOT NULL` predicate, to make the resultset match.

(We don't have any examples of rows that have a NULL value for uid; but just something to be aware of in a more general case.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `SELECT` statement for the `NOT IN`

```
SELECT
    reports_accreditallfr.cn,
    reports_accreditallfr.uid,
    reports_accreditallfr.supervisor
FROM
    reports_accreditallfr
WHERE
    reports_accreditallfr.uid NOT IN (SELECT reports_accreditallfr.supervisor FROM reports_accreditallfr)
```

You could also simplify your statement to the following:

```
SELECT
    cn,
    uid,
    supervisor
FROM
    reports_accreditallfr
WHERE
    uid NOT IN (SELECT supervisor FROM reports_accreditallfr)
```